# Context Menu background color upon selection in ListView no longer grays out

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView of items which when you click on will change its background color (and will keep the background color even after restarting the app). This is to indicate that the item has been read (the expanded view opens in VieWPager).  My problem is, since I have been able to change the background color of ListView items (for those that have been clicked), when i long press to bring up the Context Menu, when selecting on an item, the background color of that item no longer greys out like it usually does. As a result, i cannot "see" what i am selecting in context mode. I really have no idea how to fix this problem. Please can someone advise?

The code that I used to change the color of background items in ListView:

```
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int postion, long id) {
    Article a = ((toReadListAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(postion);


    // Clicked on items are flagged.
    a.setRead(true);
    saveToReadList(toReadList);

    ..........
```

Custom adapter:

```
 // Defining custom adapter
private class toReadListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    public toReadListAdapter(ArrayList<Article> listToRead) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, listToRead);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_articlelistfragment, null);
        }

        Article en = getItem(position);

        .....

          //if the article has been clicked on, then read value is true. Background is set to green.
        if(en.isRead()){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9"));
        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        }


        return convertView;
```

Comment: are your list items selectable and is that selected color the same as your non read color?

Comment: the selected colour is green, and the non-selected is white.  Upon selecting on an item in the ListView, it exapnds into a new activity via ViewPager

Comment: You'll need to add more to this question for anyone to help you like your long press implementation and your Article class